# Handle subclass of arraylist as an array

Tags: jersey, tomcat7, java-6, swagger

We have an Jersey REST-API annotated with Swagger annotations.
The swagger UI works with the exception of one class. This class extends `ArrayList<T>`. And I expect that this class is handled by swagger as an array. But this is not the case. It is handled like any other complex object and its public members are shown in swagger-ui.

Here a code summary of my class:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE, isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE) 
public class ArraySubClass extends ArrayList<ElementClass> implements IAnInterface {

// constructors...

    public A getA() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Swagger shows this class as model object:

```
"ArraySubClass": {

    "id": "ArraySubClass",
    "description": "",
    "properties": {
        "a": {
            "$ref": "A"
        },
        "empty": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "size": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do, so that swagger does **handle the class** (extending from `ArrayList<T>`) **as an array** and that swagger just shows its elements and not other properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rather use the class ElementClass directly in swagger as this

```
@ApiOperation(value = "/yourEndPoint", notes = "comment for endpoint", response = ElementClass.class, responseContainer = "List")
```

So that you'll present the content of your class as a list in the return and not your ArraySubClass that may contains others datas / stuff you want to hide ! :)

For more info : see [response container](http://aredko.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/swagger-make-developers-to-love-working.html)